# Can't retrieve data from XML in php

Tags: php, xml, data-retrieval

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" standalone="no"?>
<Xmd_toc REPOSITORY_FORMAT="1.0" PRXML_VER="2.0" PUBLICATION="HeadLine" PUBLICATION_DESCRIPTION="" ISSUE_DATE="15/12/2012" RELEASE_NO="WEB_2012_12_15_DoublePages" LANGUAGE="English">
    <Head_np>
        <Meta PAGES_NUMBER="80" SOURCE_TYPE="PDF" SOURCE_RESOLUTION="216" IMAGES_RESOLUTION="150" PAGE_THUMBNAIL_RESOLUTION="142" PAGE_PREVIEW_RESOLUTION="30" DEFAULT_IMG_EXT="png" DEFAULT_PREVIEW_IMG_EXT="png" BASE_HREF="HeadLine/2012/12/15" PDF_DESTINATION_MAPPED="OLV0_Page_0001" TITLE_SNP_EXT="png" AD_SNP_EXT="jpg" IMAGE_SNP_EXT="jpg" MULTI_LAYER_PAGE_IMG="true">
            <Publisher XMD_VER="2.6.238.11" ACROBAT_VER="8.14" PUBLISHER="Olive" PROFILE_ID="HeadLine.ini">
                <PublishDate>Fri, 14 Dec 2012 19:18:14 UTC</PublishDate>
                <PublishSWFCompatible>false</PublishSWFCompatible>
            </Publisher>
            <Resolutions>
                <Resolution DEFAULT="true">142</Resolution>
            </Resolutions>
            <LayerResolutions>
                <Resolution DEFAULT="true" GRAPHIC_IMG_EXT="jpg">142</Resolution>
            </LayerResolutions>
        </Meta>
        <Link SOURCE="WEB_2012_12_15_DoublePages.pdf"/>
        <DataFiles>
            <Files TYPE="DOC_PDF" PRESENT="1"/>
            <Files TYPE="PAGE_PDF" PRESENT="0"/>
            <Files TYPE="DOC_IMG" PRESENT="0"/>
            <Files TYPE="PAGE_IMG" PRESENT="0"/>
            <Files TYPE="PAGE_VIEW_IMG" PRESENT="1"/>
            <Files TYPE="PAGE_PREVIEW_IMG" PRESENT="1"/>
            <Files TYPE="PRIMITIVE_IMG" PRESENT="1"/>
            <Files TYPE="SNIPPET_IMG" PRESENT="1"/>
        </DataFiles>
    </Head_np>
    <Body_np>
        <Section NAME="Cover">
            <Page PAGE_NO="1" NAME="" ID="Pg001" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/1/Pg001">
                <Entity ENTITY_TYPE="Article" PAGE_NO="1" NAME="Main News" ID="Ar00100" HREF="/1/Ar00100" SIZE="Small" IMAGES_RESOLUTION="150"/>
            </Page>
            <Page PAGE_NO="2" NAME="" ID="Pg002" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/2/Pg002"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="3" NAME="" ID="Pg003" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/3/Pg003"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="4" NAME="" ID="Pg004" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/4/Pg004"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="5" NAME="" ID="Pg005" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/5/Pg005"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="6" NAME="" ID="Pg006" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/6/Pg006">
                <Entity ENTITY_TYPE="Article" PAGE_NO="6" NAME="Local News" ID="Ar00600" HREF="/6/Ar00600" SIZE="Small" IMAGES_RESOLUTION="150"/>
            </Page>
            <Page PAGE_NO="7" NAME="" ID="Pg007" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/7/Pg007"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="8" NAME="" ID="Pg008" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/8/Pg008"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="9" NAME="" ID="Pg009" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/9/Pg009"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="10" NAME="" ID="Pg010" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/10/Pg010"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="11" NAME="" ID="Pg011" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/11/Pg011"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="12" NAME="" ID="Pg012" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/12/Pg012"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="13" NAME="" ID="Pg013" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/13/Pg013"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="14" NAME="" ID="Pg014" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/14/Pg014"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="15" NAME="" ID="Pg015" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/15/Pg015"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="16" NAME="" ID="Pg016" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/16/Pg016"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="17" NAME="" ID="Pg017" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/17/Pg017"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="18" NAME="" ID="Pg018" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/18/Pg018"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="19" NAME="" ID="Pg019" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/19/Pg019"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="20" NAME="" ID="Pg020" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/20/Pg020"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="21" NAME="" ID="Pg021" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/21/Pg021"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="22" NAME="" ID="Pg022" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/22/Pg022"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="23" NAME="" ID="Pg023" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/23/Pg023"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="24" NAME="" ID="Pg024" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/24/Pg024"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="25" NAME="" ID="Pg025" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/25/Pg025"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="26" NAME="" ID="Pg026" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/26/Pg026"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="27" NAME="" ID="Pg027" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/27/Pg027"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="28" NAME="" ID="Pg028" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/28/Pg028"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="29" NAME="" ID="Pg029" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/29/Pg029"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="30" NAME="" ID="Pg030" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/30/Pg030"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="31" NAME="" ID="Pg031" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/31/Pg031"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="32" NAME="" ID="Pg032" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/32/Pg032"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="33" NAME="" ID="Pg033" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/33/Pg033"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="34" NAME="" ID="Pg034" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/34/Pg034"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="35" NAME="" ID="Pg035" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/35/Pg035"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="36" NAME="" ID="Pg036" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/36/Pg036"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="37" NAME="" ID="Pg037" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/37/Pg037"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="38" NAME="" ID="Pg038" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/38/Pg038"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="39" NAME="" ID="Pg039" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/39/Pg039"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="40" NAME="" ID="Pg040" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/40/Pg040"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="41" NAME="" ID="Pg041" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/41/Pg041"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="42" NAME="" ID="Pg042" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/42/Pg042"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="43" NAME="" ID="Pg043" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/43/Pg043"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="44" NAME="" ID="Pg044" PAGE_TYPE="Double_First" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 3243 1901" HREF="/44/Pg044"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="45" NAME="" ID="Pg045" PAGE_TYPE="Double_Second" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="-1621 0 1621 1901" HREF="/45/Pg045"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="46" NAME="" ID="Pg046" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/46/Pg046"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="47" NAME="" ID="Pg047" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/47/Pg047"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="48" NAME="" ID="Pg048" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/48/Pg048">
                <Entity ENTITY_TYPE="Article" PAGE_NO="48" NAME="China &amp; International" ID="Ar04800" HREF="/48/Ar04800" SIZE="Small" IMAGES_RESOLUTION="150"/>
            </Page>
            <Page PAGE_NO="49" NAME="" ID="Pg049" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/49/Pg049">
                <Entity ENTITY_TYPE="Article" PAGE_NO="49" NAME="Finance" ID="Ar04900" HREF="/49/Ar04900" SIZE="Small" IMAGES_RESOLUTION="150"/>
            </Page>
            <Page PAGE_NO="50" NAME="" ID="Pg050" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/50/Pg050">
                <Entity ENTITY_TYPE="Article" PAGE_NO="50" NAME="Property" ID="Ar05000" HREF="/50/Ar05000" SIZE="Small" IMAGES_RESOLUTION="150"/>
            </Page>
            <Page PAGE_NO="51" NAME="" ID="Pg051" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/51/Pg051"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="52" NAME="" ID="Pg052" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/52/Pg052">
                <Entity ENTITY_TYPE="Article" PAGE_NO="52" NAME="Sports" ID="Ar05200" HREF="/52/Ar05200" SIZE="Small" IMAGES_RESOLUTION="150"/>
            </Page>
            <Page PAGE_NO="53" NAME="" ID="Pg053" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/53/Pg053"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="54" NAME="" ID="Pg054" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/54/Pg054"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="55" NAME="" ID="Pg055" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/55/Pg055"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="56" NAME="" ID="Pg056" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/56/Pg056"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="57" NAME="" ID="Pg057" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/57/Pg057"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="58" NAME="" ID="Pg058" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/58/Pg058"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="59" NAME="" ID="Pg059" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/59/Pg059"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="60" NAME="" ID="Pg060" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/60/Pg060">
                <Entity ENTITY_TYPE="Article" PAGE_NO="60" NAME="Feature" ID="Ar06000" HREF="/60/Ar06000" SIZE="Small" IMAGES_RESOLUTION="150"/>
            </Page>
            <Page PAGE_NO="61" NAME="" ID="Pg061" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/61/Pg061"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="62" NAME="" ID="Pg062" PAGE_TYPE="Double_First" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 3243 1901" HREF="/62/Pg062"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="63" NAME="" ID="Pg063" PAGE_TYPE="Double_Second" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="-1621 0 1621 1901" HREF="/63/Pg063"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="64" NAME="" ID="Pg064" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/64/Pg064"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="65" NAME="" ID="Pg065" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/65/Pg065"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="66" NAME="" ID="Pg066" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/66/Pg066"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="67" NAME="" ID="Pg067" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/67/Pg067"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="68" NAME="" ID="Pg068" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/68/Pg068">
                <Entity ENTITY_TYPE="Article" PAGE_NO="68" NAME="Entertainment" ID="Ar06800" HREF="/68/Ar06800" SIZE="Small" IMAGES_RESOLUTION="150"/>
            </Page>
            <Page PAGE_NO="69" NAME="" ID="Pg069" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/69/Pg069"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="70" NAME="" ID="Pg070" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/70/Pg070"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="71" NAME="" ID="Pg071" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/71/Pg071"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="72" NAME="" ID="Pg072" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/72/Pg072"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="73" NAME="" ID="Pg073" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/73/Pg073"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="74" NAME="" ID="Pg074" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/74/Pg074"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="75" NAME="" ID="Pg075" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/75/Pg075"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="76" NAME="" ID="Pg076" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/76/Pg076"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="77" NAME="" ID="Pg077" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/77/Pg077"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="78" NAME="" ID="Pg078" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/78/Pg078"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="79" NAME="" ID="Pg079" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/79/Pg079"/>
            <Page PAGE_NO="80" NAME="" ID="Pg080" PAGE_TYPE="Single" PAGE_WIDTH="1622" PAGE_HEIGHT="1902" CROP_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" MEDIA_BOX="0 0 1621 1901" HREF="/80/Pg080"/>
        </Section>
    </Body_np>
</Xmd_toc>
```

I used this code to get the page_no and Name inside  but does not work, why? thanks

```
foreach($xml->children() as $Page){
      echo $Page->Entity['PAGE_NO'];
      echo "<br />";
      echo $Page->Entity['NAME'];
      echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: what does `$xml` contain?

Comment: xml is the input xml file object

Comment: Didn't you get an error message of sorts? (Yes, enable error_reporting).

Comment: how do you read it? simplexml?

Comment: no error message, i tried print_r of the xml file to ensure the xml file is exist

Comment: $xml = simplexml_load_file('demo'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'data.xml') 
       or die("Error: Cannot create object");

Comment: Is it the code for getting data is wrong? Do I need to care about the other node eg. section , Body_np etc...?

Comment: Yes, you need to skip over two or three other node levels, before foreaching over the `<Page>` entries.

Comment: sorry, do you mean i need foreach($xml->children() as $Body_np){foreach($xml->children() as $Section){foreach($xml->children() as $Page)...?

Comment: @user782104 Do you really think one can answer your 'question' having that input? -1

Comment: sorry , this is the whole xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to skip over the root element (implict in `$xml` already) and `<Body_Np>` and your `<Section>` before you can loop over the `<Page>` entries:

```
foreach ($xml->Body_np[0]->Section[0]->children() as $Page) {
```

When in doubt, use [`print_r`](http://php.net/print_r).